# Execute $watch or $observe once

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch and an observe which execute the same function. However, there are cases where both of them trigger, running the function twice per digest.

Is there a way to only execute one or the other, with the observe taking priority over the watch.

```
var myFunction = function{
   //my code
}

scope.$parent.$watch('Parent.Var', myFunction);
attrs.$observe('myAttr', myFunction);
```

I am currently using a 100ms timeout, however some cases it still triggers both. I feel that mechanism is a bit tricky, since it deppends on how well browsers respond.

Clarifying my question a bit more: My scope updates the Parent.var, which will then trigger the watch. During the same digest cycle it will update the myAttr later, which will then trigger the observe.

What i'm after is some sort of mechanism that waits until the digest cycle is over, and runs only the observe if both the watch and the observe were triggered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both answers!

I mixed both and reached a solution.

```
var myFunctionWait = function(){
   // wait a bit, to give $observe a chance to fire.
   setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(); }, 100);
}

var myAttrFunction = function(){
   unbindWatch();
   myFunction();
}

var unbindWatch = scope.$parent.$watch('Parent.Var', myFunctionWait );
attrs.$observe('myAttr', myAttrFunction);
```

Unfortunately i do not have reputation yet to upvote :(

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a lock variable.

```
var myFunctionLock = false;

var myFunction = function(){
    if (myFunctionLock) return;
    myFunctionLock = true

    //my code

    myFunctionLock = false
}

scope.$parent.$watch('Parent.Var', myFunction);
attrs.$observe('myAttr', myFunction);
```

If there is a chance that the function returns before reaching the end, you probably want to add some sort of time limit to the top as well, like

```
    ...
    if (myFunctionLock) return;
    myFunctionLock = true
    var t = setTimeout(function(){ myFunctionLock = false; }, 500);
    ...
    myFunctionLock = false
    clearTimeout(t);
```

so that the function becomes usable again.

To achieve some sort of "priority execution" for the $observe, you could have other calls simply wait a bit, to give $observe a change to fire and skip to the head of the line.

```
var myFunctionWait = function(){
    // wait a bit, to give $observe a chance to fire.
    setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(); }, 100);
}

scope.$parent.$watch('Parent.Var', myFunctionWait);
attrs.$observe('myAttr', myFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i have edited my question in hopes of making it a bit more clear. I feel the lock only works with the timeout since the function runs pretty fast, and i would like to avoid timers bigger than 100 / 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can always unbind $watch or $observe at any point of time in your code so that it will not be executed again.

### Way to unbind $watch:

```
var unbindWatch = scope.$parent.$watch('Parent.Var', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // @TODO add your code here which need to be executed
  unbindWatch();
}
```

### Way to unbind $observe:

```
var unbindObserve = attrs.$observe('myAttr', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // @TODO add your code here which need to be executed
  unbindObserve();
}
```

So the above code would make sure that will execute only once.